# Error al acceder a propiedad de objeto con Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

Estoy trabajando con `React Native` y me acabo de topar con un error un tanto extraño. Al obtener mi objeto con los siguientes datos:

```
Object {
   "coords": Object {
      "accuracy": 15.28600025177002,
       "altitude": 2233,
       "heading": 0,
       "latitude": -------,
       "longitude": ------,
       "speed": 0,
      },
    "mocked": false,
    "timestamp": 1592163692035,
        }
```

Puedo acceder a el de la siguiente manera `valor.coords` dandome los siguientes datos:

```
Object {
    "accuracy": 14.409000396728516,
    "altitude": 2233,
    "heading": 80.9710693359375,
    "latitude": -------,
    "longitude": -------,
    "speed": 0.003523211693391204,
  }
```

Pero posterior a eso ya no puedo obtener ninguno de esos individualmente. Por ejemplo, si quisiera acceder a el dato de velocidad si trato `valor.coords.speed`, el valor que necesito es `0.003523211693391204`, pero por alguna razón obtengo el siguiente error:

`TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'valor.coords')`

La manera en que la uso es la siguiente:

`<Text style={styles.velocidad}>Velocidad: {valor.coords.speed}</Text>`, ¿alguna idea de como solucionar este problema?.

Comment: Mmmm no entiendo los valores de latitude y longitude. 
¿Los escribiste con guiones para el ejemplo, o te viene así?

Comment: Los puse así porque son mis datos personales

Comment: Ok, lo imaginaba. Como obtenés los datos? es decir, el contexto cual sería? vienen en un fetch? El objeto que pegaste ahí, está impreso desde la consola?
Se me ocurre que si el objeto que tenés adentro lo interpretás cono json, es un json inválido, ya que tiene una coma al final de speed. Para que sea Json valido, esa coma no debería estar. Quizás te venga como otro tipo de dato, o te venga encodeado como jsonstring. Me parece raro que te tome como object y te imprima igual las keys con comillas... por eso, quizás el problema es que lo estés parseando como json, y esa coma no te funciona.

Comment: Sería bueno ver un poco de código para saber si estás creando las variables/objetos en el mismo contexto.